# tableview: search bar that uses indexPath.row

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have researched how to make a search bar in a table view, but they all make their data for the tableview different so when I try to use their method on my tableview, the titles, details, and pictures are misplaced. **How would I make a search bar from my code?**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var cellContent = ["not actual data for privacy reasons, there are 23 strings in here"]

var cellDetail = ["not actual data for privacy reasons, there are 23 strings in here"]

var cellImage = ["not actual data for privacy reasons, there are 23 names of images in here"]

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("0", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("1", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("2", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 3 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("3", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 4 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("4", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 5 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("5", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 6 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("6", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 7 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("7", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 8 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("8", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 9 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("9", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 10 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("10", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 11 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("11", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 12 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("12", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 13 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("13", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 14 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("14", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 15 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("15", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 16 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("16", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 17 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("17", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 18 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("18", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 19 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("19", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 20 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("20", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 21 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("21", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    } else if indexPath.row == 22 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("22", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    }

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {

    return 23
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!)
    if (cell == cell) {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    var imageName = UIImage(named: cellImage[indexPath.row])
    //let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    //let cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    //let art = cellContent[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.cellDetail[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = imageName
    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.1)

        return cell
    }
        return cell

}


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you have to check if the `TableView` is in search mode or regular mode. And then you can have the `TableView` dequeue the appropriate cell from the appropriate data source depending on which state the table is in. Best done with an `if...else`

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note to tidy up your code. Rather than doing an if statement for each indexPath on didSelect you can write it once turning the indexPath row into a string and using that as the segue identifier:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(String(indexPath.row), sender: self)
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```